# How can I append data from another array within a forEach?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to have an api return a few arrays, and have my code append each array item to a new Discord embed. So far my code is:

```js
cleanedSearchArray.forEach( lyricResult => lyricSearchEmbed.addField('\u200B' + lyricResult, 'by ' + cleanedSearchArtistArray.forEach()));
```

I'm trying to have my embed output:

```
song0
by artist0
song1
by artist1
song2
by artist2
```

but instead, I get:

```
song0
by function forEach() { [native code] }
song1
by function forEach() { [native code] }
song2
by function forEach() { [native code] }
```

Any way to get the desired output?

BTW `cleanedSearchArray` includes [song0, song1, song2] and `cleanedSearchArtistArray` includes [artist0, artist1, artist2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that output because you're not doing anything with your second `forEach()` loop `cleanedSearchArtistArray.forEach()`.

But regardless, you could achieve what you want by using `join()`

```js
cleanedSearchArray.forEach( lyricResult => lyricSearchEmbed.addField('\u200B' + lyricResult, 'by ' + cleanedSearchArtistArray.join(', '))); // This will result in: song1 by artist1, artist2
```